# Custom URL in mvc .net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I currently have the following url implemented:
`https://example.com/controller/challenge/{params}`
and would like to create a second url that accepts a different set of parameters: `https://example.com/controller/v2/challenge/{params}`.

I cannot seem to get the "v2" to be hardcoded into the url path. Rather, the only way I can make it work at the moment is using `https://example.com/controller/challengev2/{params}`

In my configuration file:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "controller", action = "Challenge", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ChallengeV2",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "controller", action = "Challengev2", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

My controller is set up like:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Challenge(string resumePath, string refid, string client_id)
{

}

[ActionName("Challengev2)]
public async Task<ActionResult> Challenge(string refid)
{

}
```

I have tried modifying the url when defining the route to:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ChallengeV2",
    url: "controller/v2/Challenge/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "controller", action = "Challengev2", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

But this seems to throw a 404 error. Is there a step that I am missing to create that endpoint?

Comment: "{controller}/v2/{action}/{id}" not working?

Comment: @MikeCheel No that also throws me a 404

Comment: Your last example is missing some {} around the controller and action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch the order you define your routes. The order plays an extremely important role.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ChallengeV2",
    url: "controller/v2/Challenge/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "controller", action = "Challengev2" }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "controller", action = "Challenge", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: That worked! Is there a reason why the order matters in this context? I would think that the v2 would make the two endpoints distinct enough to not matter in that case.

Comment: The order matters because the 1st route is checked, if it passes, it stops there. Unfortunately, a more detailed explanation into the context would require some more information. A dummy call that works and one that fails on your previous setup for example.

Comment: I set the two urls to be: {controller}/{action}/{id} and distinguished them with their actions as challenge and challengev2. So when I called example.com/controller/challenge/{3params} and example.com/controller/challengev2/{1param} that worked. This would be before the two definitions got flipped.

Comment: Your failed call would have probably hit your default route, however the parameter list didn't match the `Action` params

Answer (score 0):

To create a v2 route prefix, I would recommend you to use [route attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#attribute-routing) instead of route map.

Using route attribute, your code would be like this:

```
public class ChallengeController
{
    [Route("/challenge/{resumePath}/{refid}/{client_id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Challenge(string resumePath, string refid, string client_id)
    {
        // ...
    }

    [Route("/v2/challenge/{refid}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Challenge(string refid)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to access the original url and it complains that the url is ambiguous between the two endpoints. Is there a reason to do this with the Route attribute?